# how to interpolation this array from sevice

Tags: angular

I make a service to inerpolate data, and all is ok but imgs array, id, img and p interpolate fine, but I tried a lot with imgs but I did;nt find a solution, thanks in advance

this is in projects.service.ts

```
const projects = [

{ 
    'id': 'project1',
'img': 'assets/project.png',
'p': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Aliquet 
 risus feugiat in ante metus.',
'imgs': [{'photo': 'assets/project.png'}, {'photo': 
'assets/project.png'}, {'photo': 'assets/project.png'} ]


 },

{ 
    'id': 'project2',
'img': 'assets/project.png',
'p': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Aliquet 
 risus feugiat in ante metus.',
'imgs': [{'photo': 'assets/project.png'}, {'photo': 
 'assets/project.png'}, {'photo': 'assets/project.png'} ]


 },

{ 
    'id': 'project3',
'img': 'assets/project.png',
'p': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Aliquet 
 risus feugiat in ante metus.',
'imgs': [{'photo': 'assets/project.png'}, {'photo': 
'assets/project.png'}, {'photo': 'assets/project.png'} ]

 }
```

];

and this in project.component.html :

```
<section>
<h3>{{project.id}}</h3>
<img src="{{project.img}}">
<p class="main-p">{{project.p}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let collection of imgs; " class="collect">
    <img src="{{collection}}">
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: URLs may be unsafe, did you read the error message? You need the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

Comment: `I tried a lot with imgs but I did;nt find a solution` <= I don't see any attempts in your question. Please update it with an [mcve] and a description of exactly what is not working in your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-static-data)

You just needed to iterate the `imgs` object **`*ngFor="let collection of project.imgs"`** like below

```
<section *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <h3>{{project.id}}</h3>
    <img src="{{project.img}}"> 
  <p class="main-p">{{project.p}}</p> 
  <div *ngFor="let collection of project.imgs" class="collect"> 
    <img src="{{collection.photo}}"> 
  </div>
</section>
```

***On a side note***: Check your assets folder if you actually have an image named `project.png` at that path as it is in your response object `projects` like `assets/project.png`

Hopefully this helps !